# How to add a variable inside the command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I took the process ID and stored it in a variable. And I navigate to another directory. Then I should pass that process ID to get results in another command. how to achieve this? I tried the below with no luck... Please help me

```
pid=$(ps -ef | grep j[a]va | grep wmip | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -n 1p)
echo $pid
#query=$(echo "cd /wmip/webMethods7/jvm/linux150/bin/ ; ./jstat -gcutil $pid")
#echo $query
result=$(cd /wmip/webMethods7/jvm/linux150/bin/ ; ./jstat -gcutil $pid)
echo $result
```

Comment: Why don't you `/wmip/webMethods7/jvm/linux150/bin/jstat -gcutil $pid` directly instead of `cd ...; ./jstat ...`?

Comment: What you tried should work as is. Execute it after `set -x` to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path of `./jstat`

Answer (score 0):

Could this work? 'pid' could be a reserved word, change it

```
jpid=$(pgrep -f 'java .*wmip')
result=$(/wmip/webMethods7/jvm/linux150/bin/jstat -gcutil $jpid)
```